# How do you reproduce a method with forwarding parameters?

Tags: ruby

I see many examples of *args and &blk being passed and cases of yield.  But let's just say I want to clone (not the clone method, but the action of cloning) a method from one Object to another.

Example:

```
class String
    def all?
        self.split("").all?
    end
end
```

How would I best handle all edge cases for optional parameters, or blocks, whatever the case may be.  This is not the only case I need to use method cloning.  I just figured since you see the method doing a modification before acting as a clone you would get the idea.

I don't want my method to bring up it's own errors.  I want the cloned method that's being called to give it's own errors.

Comment: @Marek No, it delegates to `Array#all?`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young you're right, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methods can be passed arguments, keyword arguments and a block. All you have to do is forward all those parameters to the method you're calling.

```
class String
  def all?(*arguments, **keyword_arguments, &block)
    chars.all? *arguments, **keyword_arguments, &block
  end
end
```

That will catch and forward everything to `Enumerable#all?`, ensuring the method can used in the same way. Note that [`String` has a `chars` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-chars) to enumerate its individual characters. Since that's what you seem to be doing, I took the liberty of using it.

Comment: Probably even better to use `each_char` instead of `chars` because `all?` is an `Enumerable` method, but, excellent answer!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `delegate` this avoids any additional method definitions unless you need to process the arguments in addition.

```
 class String
   extend Forwardable
   delegate :all? => :chars
 end
```

When you call `String.all?` to will now call `String.chars.all?` and you can pass the same arguments as if you had called the chained method directly.

Comment: I like this answer.  I will experiment with this solution.

Comment: @6ftDan I find `delegate` to be under utilized take a look at [`Forwardable`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) you can even `delegate` methods to `instance variables` directly which I have found highly useful for collection classes.